# Problem to restrict duplicate arraylist addition

Tags: android, arraylist, onclicklistener

Activity.class:

```
holder.txt_AddToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {

     ActivityMyCartDetails.holdMyCartArrayList.add(new HoldMyCart(Subproductname, Subproductamount, product_image, qty, product_type_id));
    }
});
```

When I am adding data and add to `ArrayList` then duplicate data enter. How to validate it if the `product_type_id` already in `ActivityMyCartDetails.holdMyCartArrayList` then can't add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
holder.txt_AddToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
     for(int i = 0; i<ActivityMyCartDetails.holdMyCartArrayList.size();i++){
         HoldMyCart holdMyCart = ActivityMyCartDetails.holdMyCartArrayList.get(i);
         // i assumed getter method for product type id(you should use your)
         if(holdMyCart.getProduct_type_id() == product_type_id){
            return;
         }
     }
     ActivityMyCartDetails.holdMyCartArrayList.add(new HoldMyCart(Subproductname, Subproductamount, product_image, qty, product_type_id));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code with an if condition like this to solve it:

Activity.class

```
holder.txt_AddToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
     if(!ActivityMyCartDetails.holdMyCartArrayList.contains(product_type_id)){
     ActivityMyCartDetails.holdMyCartArrayList.add(new HoldMyCart(Subproductname, Subproductamount, product_image, qty, product_type_id));
}
    }
});
```

Comment: it will not work because `arraylist` contains `object` not value.

Comment: use this condition i think it work fine. if(!ActivityMyCartDetails.holdMyCartArrayList.contains(new HoldMyCart(Subproductname, Subproductamount, product_image, qty, product_type_id))){

Comment: @ThoriyaPrahalad you check with `new instance` so how will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try to maintain another list for `product_type_id` and check during addition of `HoldMyCart`

```
List<String> productIds = new ArrayList<>();

holder.txt_AddToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {

        if(!productIds.contains(product_type_id)) {
            productIds.add(product_type_id);
            ActivityMyCartDetails.holdMyCartArrayList.add(new HoldMyCart(Subproductname, Subproductamount, product_image, qty, product_type_id));
        }
    }
});
```